# "Contemporary Christian Music" but for other religions?

Tags: musicology, styles

[Contemporary Christian music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_Christian_music) (or CCM -- and occasionally "inspirational music") is a genre of modern popular music which is lyrically focused on matters concerned with the Christian faith.

Do religions other than Christianity have their own versions of this genre?

What would be some notable examples of artists and songs in those genres?

To clarify what I mean through an example:  "[Jesus, Take the Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus,_Take_the_Wheel)" is a song recorded by American country music artist Carrie Underwood.

It became a top twenty hit on the Billboard Hot 100 chart, won Grammys for Best Female Country Vocal Performance and Best Country Song, and it won Single of the Year at the 2005 Academy of Country Music Awards. The song ranked number four on CMT's 40 Greatest Songs of the Decade.

I'm trying to imagine some sort of "Buddha/Krishna/Muhammad Take the Wheel" song, or anything remotely like it, in any culture, but I'm coming up very short, but I also don't have a very good imagination.

Comment: here are some examples:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QU8IJ-3aEQ0 ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xo2BjNxmCk&list=PLEC7A512AF6629AFC  ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zdcth9NndEA (ipi tombi is rather ethno than religious - and christian influences - I don't understand all the lyrics)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7W9YBscll28

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. [Here](https://youtu.be/ordi4e72nVY) is a North Indian  hymn to the guru. [South Indian](https://youtu.be/r4FUQxn4CnY) Krishna with subtitles. [Central Indian](https://youtu.be/O0MTxpOQ8RE)

Comment: I see you've added a clarification/elaboration of your question. Thanks. In that context it needs to be understood that almost no world religion is as personality-centered as Christianity. Even the extreme personality-centered parts of Hinduism like Krishna-cult folks (seen in the west as Hare Krishna) are embedded in a context of abstract concepts like karma, maya etc. And Buddhism Zen Taoism etc are even more impersonal. But are you looking for something more pop-songish? [To Shiva](https://youtu.be/mH80DUtmLzI)  Or children singing [to the goddess](https://youtu.be/Np28O3Y_P2o)

Comment: Gave these examples since even in spite of not being familiar with the language, the alliterative quality is still prominent... Hopefully

Comment: @Rusi Thanks those look a lot like what I was thinking of!  If you make your comment into an answer then I'll give you a vote.

Comment: @Rusi - I also think you've nailed it with your comment about personality. It explains the triviality of much modern and suposedly inspirational Christian music, .

Comment: @PeterJ And I'm uncomfortable being the one saying that As a staunch perennialist putting any one religion above or below another should be abhorrent and ridiculous. I correlate the problem with the Nicene council which kicked out and genocided the gnostics, putting philosophy and religion into "perennial" conflict.

Comment: I don't know if it matters for your question, but CCM is sacred lyrically but adopted _secular_ pop music style. Are you looking for that cross over of sacred/secular in the other cultures? Surely there is sacred music all over the world. Whether it is analogous to CCM is a special kind of comparison.

Comment: @Rusi - I just had to come back to agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested collating into answer-form.
Could fill out more interesting  details of singer/composer in some cases if desired

## Arunachala Shiva

## Nighalo gheuna

## Bhaja Govindam

## Teertha Vitthala

## Sunta hai Guru Gyani

## Shiva Tandava Stotram

## Ayi Giri Nandini

## Hanuman chalisa

## Ram Simar

Answer (score 4):

I think most religions have "ritual" music and in modern times this probably has evolved into something like gospel or what you are referring to.

Some examples are:

Jewish cantorial music.  This can be very inspirational, very emotional.  In modern synagogues such music will be played with a modern "folk music" style twist.  There are also modern orthodox jewish musical groups with a Rock or Jazz sound that play religious themed lyrics.

Another is Hindu and other Indian religious groups having religious themed music during festivals.

Islam often signs prayers.

Comment: I want to note that contemporary christian music is not gospel (CCM is more like mainstream pop, whereas gospel is typically referring to music rooted in southern black protestant traditions).